# Get photos from Address book in iphone Application

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get contact name,photos from Addressbook in my iphone application. I am able to get contacts and store in to array.but now know how also get contacts photos.the code i am using is as follows.

```
ABAddressBookRef ab=ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *arrTemp=(NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);  

arrContact=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0;i<[arrTemp count];i++) 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dicContact=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *str=(NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue([arrTemp objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    @try 
    {
        [dicContact setObject:str forKey:@"name"];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        [dicContact release];
        continue;
    }
    [arrContact addObject:dicContact];
    NSLog(@"mohit inside the loop");
    [dicContact release];
}
```

I want to to get both contacts photo and name in that array(arrContacts) then display them in table. Please give me guideline. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In ARC mode

```
 NSData  *imgData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *) ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(record, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
```

where record is the object of class

```
ABRecordRef
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 4+ you can get the image with :

```
ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize);
```

or

```
ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
```

Comment: what is the data type of person.is its a type of NSMutableArray?

Comment: ABRecordRef , same as [arrTemp objectAtIndex:i] that you are using for ABRecordCopyValue. To find this out yourself type ABPersonCopyImageData in Xcode then alt click it, magic, click it again in the popup that appears to go to the full documentation.