# ios: how can i get the thumbnail image from the address book by using the mobile number of person?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get photos from Address book in iphone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488675/get-photos-from-address-book-in-iphone-application)

i am new in iphone development. In my application i am using the `<AddressBook/AddressBook.h> and <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>` framework for get the person details from the address book.

i am have `recName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);`
and `ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    recNumber.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);`

after that i am saving my recName and recNumber into sqlite database.

then i m executing some query statement into database for getting the recName and recNumber value that maximum repeated into db.

now i have recname and recnumber from the database, i want corresponding image of person from the address book.

how can i get the image of corresponding person from the address book?

Comment: NSData *contactImageData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(personRef,kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

Comment: hi divya..thanks for reply but i want to to get the image by parring the mobile number instead of personRef.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];
  CFRelease(imageData);
```

Comment: NSData  *imgData = (NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
    thumbnailImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

how can i get the image by passing the mobile number instead of person/refperson?

Comment: @KiranPatel where should this code go? Please give OP some context.