# Read contacts with pictures on IOS?

Tags: ios, contacts, image

Hey friends currently i am working with backup and restore app in IOS every things works fine, i can read contacts, but i got stuck in reading contacts with picture, any answers related are appreciated.

thank you

Comment: can you elaborate on what you've tried to do so far, e.g. code or explanations, etc.?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late response can you say me whether is it possible to read a contact with picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code helps to get contact picture in ios 4 +

```
ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize);
```

or

```
ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
```

REF : [Get photos from Address book in iphone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488675/get-photos-from-address-book-in-iphone-application)